# Is there a way to run one application in Full Screen mode on one display and still be able to view and access applications on a second display?

Tags: macos, display, fullscreen

When I make an app go full screen on my primary display - *a 24" Apple Display* - everything previously visible and accessible on my second display - *my MacBook Pro screen* - is hidden by the default Lion background image.

[image: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png]

Is there a way to run one app in Full Screen mode on one display and still be able to view and access applications on secondary display(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built in full screen (Lion) dominates both screens - and I've not been able to find any setting which lets me use the other one for anything else.

The fix I use for this is [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) - which enables me to maximise on each screen - but this isn't quite full screen and doesn't provide entirely the same experience. It is, however, a good compromise.

Comment: This is clearly the main workable "non-solution" since the full screen dark linen effect on secondary screens hasn't been tweaked, hacked or adjusted in a reliable way yet.

Comment: I agree - although this functionality is something that OSX should have baked in. They took the hint with Growl, I wonder if they will with Divvy.

Comment: I'll take a look at Divvy. Thanks. 

Hopefully this will be resolved soon within OS X.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what Apple do with window management as OSX draws closer to iOS, but divvy is definitely my favourite so far.