# Why does a full screen application black out the other display?

Tags: macos, display, fullscreen

When I go into (at least some) full screen app(s) the other  display gets blacked out. An example is Zoom.  Is there a workaround for this that would allow me to continue using the unused display for other applications?

Note there is a similar question here : [Is there a way to run one application in Full Screen mode on one display and still be able to view and access applications on a second display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40765/is-there-a-way-to-run-one-application-in-full-screen-mode-on-one-display-and-sti) .  However that question  is very old (2012 OS/X Lion) and does not have any OS/X builtin answer but instead depends on a third party library.

I am on `catalina` on a macbook PRO.

Comment: Check System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces. I can't test to be certain (because it totally messes up my carefully assigned Spaces) but with that off you get a blank 2nd screen & with it on you don't - as the other screen is a different Space. Alternatively, don't use fullscreen, just maximise instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Enable the setting `System Preferences > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces`**:

[image: Enable setting "Displays have separate Spaces"]

It requires you to log out/back in, and then you will be able to use other displays as regular when an app is full screen in one of the displays.

Comment: Note that this solves the OP issue, but means you can't have applications span multiple monitors. So many issues are caused by MacOS's insistence on the context-based menu bar, rather than just allowing menus on a per-window basis.

Comment: Me too.  But I don't _want_ to use Displays have Separate Spaces.

Comment: Apple usually makes brilliant decisions, but this one leaves me scratching my head. Who wants to disable their other monitors just because they want to see as much of a document as possible?